# AudioToolbox to play nsdata in download

Tags: ios, download, nsdata, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to play audio with audiotoolbox in xcode. I search for this but the documentation is too little. I want play nsdata while i download it from internet. 
I look this link: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html
and the apple developer documentation but i can't understand what i have to do to cast nsdata (that is not complete because it is in download) in data that audiotoolbox can read.
With apple documentation i understand the strutture the i must allocate:

```
typedef struct MyAQStruct {
    AudioFileID                     mAudioFile;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription     mDataFormat;
    AudioQueueRef                   mQueue;
    AudioQueueBufferRef             mBuffers[kNumberBuffers];
    SInt64                          mCurrentPacket;
    UInt32                          mNumPacketsToRead;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription    *mPacketDescs;
    bool                            mDone;
}myAQStruct;
```

and the callback function the i have to call for play, but which of the variabile in this struct rapresent the data? maybe i think audiostreambasicdescription. or is audiofileid?
And how can i cast nsdata into this type?

Comment: You do know you can simply pass a URL to AVPlayer right?

Comment: Yes but in this way i can't save data ho the url. So, is there a way to do this with AVAudioPlay if i download data with a NSURLConnection?

Comment: If you can download it with NSURLConnection, then you can save it and load the file to AVPlayer. If you want to "Stram" the url and save the data you have 2 options, use something like https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit or even add an AudioTap to to the AP;ayerItems AVAsset. You can look at Apple's MTAudioProcessingTap example for how to add the AudioTap, then simply write the Data to a new AVAsset.